# DataGridview search: show only searchresult and hide other rows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

What should I add to my code to only show the results of my search?

Right now when I search the searchresult becomes selected (highlighted) and the others remain the same.

Been trying to hide the other rows but without any success (and only show the searchresult, alone). Any suggestions?
Im using a datagridview.

My code:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search = textBox1.Text;

    for (int i = 0; i < dgTest.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dgTest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == search)
        {
            dgTest.Rows[i].Selected = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            dgTest.Rows[i].Selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgTest.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dgTest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "search")
    {
        dgTest.Rows[i].Selected = true;
        dgTest.Rows[i].Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        dgTest.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        dgTest.Rows[i].Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If your DataGridView is not bound to a data source, then setting the row's Visible property to false will hide it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgTest.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = dgTest.Rows[i];

        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == search)
        {
            row.Selected = true;
            row.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            row.Selected = false;
            row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

(I removed the 'break' command, as even after you have found the matching row, you would want to continue and hide the other rows.)

If you're using DataBinding, though, it's not so easy, as shown in [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/Vsexpressvcs/thread/606c4ba0-754e-4789-8d7b-7fc428b76ba6).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am using databinding so it became harder unfortunately. :P